# Dynamically accessing Ruby JSON object variables

Tags: json, ruby

```
puts @file
# {
#   "0.js": "js/0.js",
#   "about-page.js": "js/about-page.js",
#   "img/heart.png": "img/ae985f1437f67f39c4393e31c6785970.png",
#   "index-page.js": "js/index-page.js",
#   "init.js": "js/init.js",
#   "main.js": "js/main.js"
# }
a = "0.js"
puts a // => "0.js"
puts @file[a] // => "0.js"  ????!!!???
```

Why the above code wouldn't work? I am expecting the last line to output `"js/0.js"` instead of `"0.js"`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your hash is getting created like this

```
{:"0.js"=>"js/0.js",
 :"about-page.js"=>"js/about-page.js",
 :"img/heart.png"=>"img/ae985f1437f67f39c4393e31c6785970.png",
 :"index-page.js"=>"js/index-page.js",
 :"init.js"=>"js/init.js",
 :"main.js"=>"js/main.js"}
```

in order to access it you need to do  `@file[:"0.js"]`

Comment: This leads to error `  Liquid Exception: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer in pages/index/index.html`

Comment: what is the output for @file.class

Comment: @file.class is `String`

Comment: Try JSON.parse(@file) too and let me know

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the string into an object using `JSON.parse()`

Then, your code will work fine.

```
require json

file = '{"0.js": "js/0.js","about-page.js": "js/about-page.js","img/heart.png": "img/ae985f1437f67f39c4393e31c6785970.png","index-page.js": "js/index-page.js","init.js": "js/init.js","main.js": "js/main.js"}'

file2 = JSON.parse(file)

==> {"0.js"=>"js/0.js", "about-page.js"=>"js/about-page.js", "img/heart.png"=>"img/ae985f1437f67f39c4393e31c6785970.png", "index-page.js"=>"js/index-page.js", "init.js"=>"js/init.js", "main.js"=>"js/main.js"}

a = "0.js"

puts a  => "0.js"

puts file2[a] // => "js/0.js"
```